# React MUI Grid seems to be causing an overflow to the page or its container

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to keep the entire page organized by applying Grid to (almost) everything on the page. The problem I keep coming across is adding some (or too many?) Grid items causes an overflow (ie. the scrollbar appears) despite the container remaining the same size. Dashboard.tsx itself is part of React-Router V6's Outlet though I'm not sure if this is relevant to the problem.

There's going to be some redundant codes here since I'm still learning the ropes with this so apologies for that.

App.tsx (part of it)

```
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }} id="nav">
      <NavBar />
        <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} id="page-body">
          <Toolbar />
          <Outlet />
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
    <Box
      sx={{
        padding: "20px"
      }}
    >
      <Grid container>
        <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
          Dashboard
        </Typography>
        <Grid
          container
          item
          xs={12}
          component={LocalizationProvider}
          dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
        >
          <Grid container item columnSpacing={2} rowSpacing={4}>
            <Grid item container xs={12}>
              <Grid
                item
                container
                component={Card}
              >
                <JobDetailPieChart />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container xs={12} lg={7}>
              <Grid
                item
                container
                component={Card}
              >
                <MachineRuntimeGantt />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container xs={12} lg={5}>
              <Grid
                item
                container
                component={Card}
              >
                <DefectParetoChart />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```

MachineRuntimeGantt.tsx (other chart components are structured the same)

```
    <Grid item container component={Box} sx={{ padding: "20px" }} spacing={2}>
      <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Typography variant={"h4"}>Machine Runtime</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <DatePicker
            label="Select Month"
            views={["month", "year"]}
            aria-label="select-month-year"
            value={selectDate}
            onChange={(newDate) => {
              setSelectDate(dayjs(newDate))
            }}
            slotProps={{
              textField: {
                fullWidth: true,
                InputLabelProps: { shrink: true }
              }
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Divider sx={{ borderBottomWidth: "4px" }} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={options}
          ref={chartComponentRef}
          {...props.chart}
        />
      </Grid>
      <ChartLegend errorTypeList={errorTypeList} />
    </Grid>
```

I suppose I've figured out that having multiple rows in the Grid causes an overflow? Unfortunately, I don't understand why that happens

Including all 3 causes overflow
[image: Including all 3 causes overflow]

2 of any of these also does it
[image: 2 of any of these also does it]

Both being on the same row (or the Pie Chart individually) doesn't cause it
[image: Both being on the same row (or the Pie Chart individually) doesn't cause it]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for helping format the question! I think I've figured out that the problem was simply that causing the vertical scrollbar to show up also triggers the horizontal one. I fixed it by:

```
html {
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}
```